# request only required data from firebase realtime database flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database

Let's say I have millions of records like [this](https://miro.medium.com/max/1050/1*c9qrlfZKkXWqrX34Ce3dmg.png). I am showing this information in `GridView`. It will take a lot of time to download the whole database and then display results. How do I download only 50 records at a time and when I am about to reach the end of list download another 50 and so on like Google image search results? Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

What you want is called pagination. I don't know about real-time databases but I do know firebase firestore provides you with tools to do that. You could check this link out for firebase firestore.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=poqTHxtDXwU&feature=emb_logo

Answer (score 1):

You can write code to fetch specific data then add a scrollController to page and a code to fetch next data whenever your scrollController reaches bottom of page.
For it you have to learn using scrollController.
https://youtu.be/pGmHYXC5MeU